How does the Paris agreement define "developing" and "developed" countries?
Text of agreement
The agreement spells out responsibilities for developing and developed countries, e.g.:


Developed country Parties should continue taking the lead by undertaking economy-wide absolute emission reduction targets. Developing country Parties should continue enhancing their mitigation efforts, and are encouraged to move over time towards economy-wide emission reduction or limitation targets in the light of different national circumstances.


Does the agreement define which countries are developed and which are developing? If so, where can I find the criteria? If not, what is stopping countries from declaring themselves as developing?

You ask if the agreement defines the terms and post a link to the full text of the agreement? Are you looking for some other definition?

First of all would that even make a difference? Like that article basically states everyone should do what they can to mitigate climate change...
Second of all there are definitions of these terms (from Wikipedia):

Developed Countries - has a high quality of life, developed economy, and advanced technological infrastructure relative to other less industrialized nations.
Developing Countries - less developed industrial base and a lower Human Development Index (HDI) relative to other countries.
Least Developed Countries - developing countries listed by the United Nations that exhibit the lowest indicators of socioeconomic development.
Small Islands Developing States (SIDS) - a grouping of developing countries which are small island countries and tend to share similar sustainable development challenges.

[Update]: For the particular treaty there is a section "Parties and Observers".
So in particular those would be the developed countries are:

Annex I Parties include the industrialized countries that were members of the OECD (Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development) in 1992, plus countries with economies in transition (the EIT Parties), including the Russian Federation, the Baltic States, and several Central and Eastern European States.

While the developed countries with the most obligations are apparently just the OECD members among the Annex I group:

Annex II Parties consist of the OECD members of Annex I, but not the EIT Parties. They are required to provide financial resources to enable developing countries to undertake emissions reduction activities under the Convention

While non-Annex I countries largely involve developing countries and those most effected by climate change due to a low coastal line:

Non-Annex I Parties are mostly developing countries. Certain groups of developing countries are recognized by the Convention as being especially vulnerable to the adverse impacts of climate change, including countries with low-lying coastal areas and those prone to desertification and drought.

and apparently also those who's economies heavily rely on fossil fuels and who are most impacted by that:

Others (such as countries that rely heavily on income from fossil fuel production and commerce) feel more vulnerable to the potential economic impacts of climate change response measures

Yet again not Annex I already and OECD membership (since 1992) mostly overlaps with "developed" anyway.
And then there is the group of Least Developed countries which apparently is maintained by the UN so the wikipedia link should already provide a good indicator. Now the website mentions 49 and the article only 45 probably those:
Samoa (graduated in January 2014)
Equatorial Guinea (graduated in June 2017)
Vanuatu (graduated in December 2020)
Bhutan (graduated in December 2023)

who've been delisted since 2014 would be the closest contenders of the difference. Now not entirely sure whether they stick with the old list or whether you should check current list. But quite frankly it's unlikely that a country that is on the list of least developed countries or recently left that is among the biggest contributors or potential donors anyway.
Also if you want to see the Annex I and non-Annex I countries that website also has a tool for that
[end of update]
Also not sure you want that to be too explicit, like if you have a list of developing and developed countries that could change over time and if you tie development to particular thresholds these might change as well, but if you outline a general sense of we need to redistribute where necessary from those who are most potent to those who are most in need. You have a general principle.
Also last not but definitely not least. That's a treaty with the aim to mitigate and fight against climate change if you're not interested you could have opted out of that or raised your concerns about these articles. So why would you play these dirty games in the first place?

Apparently it does matter: https://www.channelnewsasia.com/singapore/singapore-climate-fund-cop27-developing-country-status-grace-fu-leon-perera-3434661

OK, but wikipedia articles aren't necessarily an indicator of how climate change treaties - not wikipedia - legally classify countries into which bucket.  And climate change is definitely an area where each country is trying to minimize its sacrifices and maximize other's efforts.  What we saw in the past is that big, poor, emitters like India and China didn't really get asked to do much and it is starting to matter as their people gets richer.  Meanwhile, countries like Canada and Australia are extremely good at playing the "awww, shucks, we're so small it hardly matters what we do" game.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica With all due respect, while those Wikipedia articles are not a conclusive answer to a specific treaty, they are very much an indicator who belongs into which bucket, especially for the UN definitions giving that this is a UN initiative... Also in the past the biggest problem to any effective action against climate change was that the U.S. as the single biggest contributor, still ahead of the EU and China despite rising emissions, either didn't join, joined without committing or committed the bare minimum or directly left... which actively incentivizes such behavior

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica That being said it's hard to argue that the U.S. or any of the other major contributors including Canada https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/annual-share-of-co2-emissions not so much Australia, but even them, would be developed rather than developing countries. OP recently mentioned Singapore which should have been in the question which might be in a dual role of being massively effected by climate change but wealthy enough to be a donor as well.

@Allure It would be great if you could add these specifics and what your are intending with that question, and what you seek for in an answer, in your question. Thanks. Nevertheless I'll update my answer.

I think the point that's a little hidden here is that the Annex I/II/other distinction, from the UNFCCC and the Kyoto Protocol, was deliberately changed for Paris so that all nations, not just Annex I, would set their own targets (with a gentle hint for developed countries to be more ambitious). Paris could have used the Annex language but did not.

@haxor789 much improved now with actual group memberships cited. +1
